# How to dereference a void pointer as a string

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, out-of-memory, void-pointers

I'm currently trying to copy a string to void pointer. 
Here is a struct of void pointer that I'm using.

```
typedef struct
  {
  struct runtime_type *runtimeTypeHead; /* Array of Runtime Types       */
  ST_INT numRuntimeTypes;               /* # of Runtime Types in array  */
  ST_CHAR *dataBuf;                     /* ptr to local data            */
  ST_VOID *userInfo;                    /* To store anything user wants.*/
                                        /* GSE code does not use it.    */
  } GSE_IEC_DATA_ENTRY;
```

And I'm using userInfo as you can see.

I've malloced the memory and used memcpy as you can see in the code below.

```
DataEntry->userInfo = safe_malloc(sizeof(ST_CHAR)*strlen(ps8tmp+1));
memcpy((ST_CHAR*)DataEntry->userInfo, ps8tmp,strlen(ps8tmp));
```

I think I didn't encounter a memory problem when I copy a string to the void pointer. 
Then, I am having a seg fault when I try to print the copied string as below.

```
printf("Updated DataEntry : %s\n", *(ST_CHAR*) DataEntry->userInfo);
```

Can anyone point out that why I'm having a segfault when I simply printing the string?

Comment: You are dereferencing the string where the %s in the printf requires a pointer to a string.  printf("Updated DataEntry : %s\n", (ST_CHAR*) DataEntry->userInfo);   Remove the * from your cast as shown here.

Comment: Yes. You were right. Thanks @CodeWhore!!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
DataEntry->userInfo = safe_malloc(sizeof(ST_CHAR)*strlen(ps8tmp+1));
```

has two problems:

1. Don't use `sizeof(char)` when allocating room for strings; it's always 1 unless you've something exotic going on with explicit 16-bit characters or something.
2. That `strlen()` usage seems broken, you are adding *inside* the parentheses, it will call `strlen()` on the string minus the first character. If the string was empty, this will give undefined behavior. You meant `strlen(ps8tmp) + 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your input @unwind. I've modified the parts as you pointed out, but the segfault error still remains :(

Comment: Actually, I've just solved the issue with the CodeWhore's comment above. Thanks for answering mine :)